# Select a row in data Table

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a data table same as the following picture and when I click on a random row, the app will be crashed and I receive an error message of below:

[image: Data Table]

```
Warning in widgetFunc() :
  renderDataTable ignores ... arguments when expr yields a datatable object; see ?renderDataTable
Warning: Unhandled error in observer: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'
observeEvent(input$responses_rows_selected)
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

I am not sure what this error message means.

server.r

```
CreateDefaultRecord <- function() {
  mydefault <- CastData(list(id = "0", name = "", used_shiny = FALSE, r_num_years = 4))
  return (mydefault)
}


 CastData <- function(data) {
   datar <- data.frame(name = data["name"], 
                       used_shiny = as.logical(data["used_shiny"]), 
                       r_num_years = as.integer(data["r_num_years"]),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

   rownames(datar) <- data["id"]
   return (datar)
 }

 UpdateInputs <- function(data, session) {
   updateTextInput(session, "id", value = unname(rownames(data)))
   updateTextInput(session, "name", value = unname(data["name"]))
   updateCheckboxInput(session, "used_shiny", value = as.logical(data["used_shiny"]))
   updateSliderInput(session, "r_num_years", value = as.integer(data["r_num_years"]))
 }

         # Select row in table -> show details in inputs
      observeEvent(input$responses_rows_selected, {
        if (length(input$responses_rows_selected) > 0) {
          data <- ReadData()[input$responses_rows_selected, ]
          UpdateInputs(data, session)
        }

      })

  # display table 

      output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable({

        #update after submit is clicked
        input$submit
        #update after delete is clicked
        input$delete
        DT::datatable(ReadData(), options = list(pageLength=3),colnames = c('ID' = 1), class = 'cell-border stripe')
      }, server = FALSE, selection = "single",
      colnames = unname(GetTableMetadata()$fields)[-1]
      )
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity : why don't you use
 `observe({if (length(input$responses_rows_selected) > 0) {
      data <- ReadData()[input$responses_rows_selected, ]
      UpdateInputs(data, session)
    }
  })`
instead of `observeEvent` ?

Comment: There is no difference if I use observe or observEvent in both case I will get same warning.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the type of `input$responses_rows_selected` ?
In your  `data <- ReadData()[input$responses_rows_selected, ]` , `input$responses_rows_selected` is neither a logical or numeric vector telling R how to subset your table.
Maybe Shiny is just treating `input$responses_rows_selected` as a character vector (as it often does), or quite surprisingly, as the error mentions (`(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'`), as a list.

Comment: I have updated my data as you can see the type of used_shiny is logical. what shall I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is because of multiple selection of rows in a datatable. 
I just add

```
selection = "single"
```

in the DT::datatable()

```
 DT::datatable(ReadData(),extensions = 'Responsive', options = list(pageLength=3),colnames = c('ID' = 1), class = 'cell-border stripe', selection = "single")
```